# Conditional select with MYSQL, performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the best way to perform a conditional query on a table that is looking like this:

```
primaryKey    question        answer    clientId
    1        are you fine?      yes        Bob
    2        are you fine?      no         Tom
    3      what is your name    Bob        Bob
    4      What is your name    Tom        Tom
```

I have to select in this table the primary key of all answers to the question "What is your name" but only for those that answered "yes" to "are you fine" (ie I want to retrieve 3)

I have try a subquery in a where in clause like so:

```
SELECT primaryKey 
FROM (`questionTable`) 
WHERE clientId IN(
SELECT clientId FROM `questionTable` 
WHERE (question = "are you fine" AND answer = "yes")
) 
AND question = "What is your name"
```

This query actually never finish, it doesn't throw any error, it just runs forever.

The only solution I found involve selecting using the clientId instead of the primary key but that is too slow and I would like to find a way to retrieve the primaryKey in one query.

Comment: You need to show the indexes of your tables (I guess you don't have any except your primary key). And you should have a question-table, where you have the columns questionid, question, e.g 1, "are you fine"and 2, "what is your name" and then just have that questionid in your table and add an index for that. Same for clientId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join the table:

```
SELECT t1.primaryKey 
FROM `questionTable` t1
INNER JOIN `questionTable` t2
    ON t1.clientId = t2.clientId
WHERE t2.question = "are you fine?" AND
      t2.answer = "yes" AND
      t1.question = "What is your name"
```

## SQLFiddle

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, about join it is more correct. But why not `using` ?

Comment: Believe it or not, I have not really seen `USING` being used too often.  I just think it is nicer to be explicit about the type of join being done.

Comment: @Manish I've added the demo. The question mark was omitted